# 16.04 Reallocate Partitions on Dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

## UBUNTU OBSERVATIONS

The 16.04 screenshot shows a 13.8 GB Capacity:

[image]

```
$ sudo lsblk -o +fstype

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT FSTYPE
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk            
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part            ntfs
├─sda2   8:2    0 193.3G  0 part            ntfs
├─sda3   8:3    0   785M  0 part            ntfs
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part            
├─sda5   8:5    0  13.1G  0 part /          ext4
└─sda6   8:6    0  15.9G  0 part [SWAP]     swap
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom             


$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  9.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda5        13G  6.5G  5.7G  54% /
tmpfs           7.8G  252K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.6G   64K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

## WINDOWS OBSERVATIONS

The Windows screenshot shows 5 partitions and for this conversation are enumerated as:

- sda1 512000
- sda2 202648387
- sda3 803840
- sda4 1
- sda5 13778944
- sda6 16684032

[image]

## GOAL

I suspect that sda6 is unused by Windows and 16.04: if this is true, then the goal is to reallocate this disk space for 16.04 usage.  I would like to prove to myself this space is unused **BEFORE** deleting partition sda6 and expanding sda5 (16.04) partition

## QUESTIONS

1. Is 16.04 using only partition sda5? (and not sda6)
2. How can I confirm that Windows and 16.04 are not using sda6?
3. sda6 does not indicate NTFS file system: reasonable to conclude Windows is not using it?
4. In order to reallocate sda6 diskspace: re next-steps to delete sda6 and expand sda5 via gParted?

Looking forward to the clever and insightful responses: any experience or lessons-learned are appreciated

[The journey continues: click here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865493/warning-moving-a-partition-might-cause-your-operating-system-to-fail-to-boot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `sudo lsblk -o +fstype` (in a Terminal) to see what partitions are mounted where. Please add the output of this command to your question.
2. Windows uses three partitions (a System partition, a Boot partition which appears to have the drive letter C:, and a Recovery partition). The same `lsblk` will show you what filesystem is in each partition so that you can deduce which partitions are used by Windows.
3. If indeed `/dev/sda6` is not in use by either Linux or Windows then you can delete it using **Gparted** (in the GUI), or, if you prefer the command line, by `sudo parted /dev/sda rm 6`.
4. If indeed `/dev/sda6` is adjacent to and to the right of `/dev/sda5` then the same **Gparted** can extend `/dev/sda5` into the now empty space. If you want to do it via the command line then you must first move the end of the partition with `sudo parted /dev/sda -- unit s resizepart 5 nnnn` when `nnnn` stands for the sector before the first sector of `/dev/sda3` as displayed by `sudo parted /dev/sda -- unit s print free`, followed by a `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda5`.

Comment: lsblk indicates sda6 FSTYPE is swap.  I think that I should 'shrink' the swap size and give that space to sda5?

Comment: Unless you need 16 GB of swap then definitely shrink it. How much swap you need depends on a variety of considerations, for example, much RAM you have and whether you want to be able to hibernate / suspend the system. If you _don't_ want to hibernate / suspend then a few GiB of swap should be enough in most cases.

Comment: There is 16GB of RAM so that could explain ~16GB of swap space.  Because the NTFS volume is far from full, It probably makes sense to shrink 16GB of NTFS space before reallocating swap space.  Thank you for preventing me from deleting my swap space

Comment: If interested: the journey continues here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/865493/warning-moving-a-partition-might-cause-your-operating-system-to-fail-to-boot