# Warning: Moving a partition might cause your operating system to fail to boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

16.04 is installed alongside Windows.  I will free space for 16.04 by shrinking the Windows partition. I understand that it is necessary to boot from a CD \ USB and use a tool like partimage to reallocate disk space.

When resizing the 16.04 partition gParted provided a warning:

> Moving a partition might cause your operating system to fail to boot

- What can be done before reallocating diskspace (via Gparted) to prevent boot failure?
- After resizing, what tasks must be performed to configure 16.04 to use the added diskspace?

## EPILOGUE

Results include 16.04 indicating in the file manager that there is now 25GB (previously 13GB).

[More information on the original state is documented (click here)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865483/16-04-reallocate-partitions-on-dual-boot-system)

The Windows partition was shrunk with the diskmgmt.msc console..  gParted was used to resize (expand) the Ubuntu partition: originally 13GB.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048   1026047   1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1026048 381746822 380720775 181.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       467251200 468858879   1607680   785M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda4       381747200 467251199  85504000  40.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       381749248 433881087  52131840  24.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       433883136 467251199  33368064  15.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

[image]

A successful chkdsk was performed on Windows and indicated "no problems found and no futher action required"

Comment: **Don't** use gparted to resize a Windows partition. Windows won't like it. Use Windows own Disk Management app. **Moving** a Windows partition using gparted will almost surely make it force a chkdsk run, or not boot at all, and you'll need a Windows repair disc. If you edit your question to include a current-window-only screenshot of gparted, I'll take a look and make a better recommendation for you.

Comment: Good to know: I shrank the Windows partition using the Windows diskmgmt.msc console. Thanks for the warning: I can not afford to bork-up my Windows partition

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right path. See my other comment below.

Comment: see my updated comments below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answers:

- nothing
- none

`gparted` message is misleading as it pertains only for OS booted with **lilo**, which is not used anymore on modern linux distro where **Grub 2** is used most of the time.

So you have nothing to do before reallocating disk space.
And ubuntu will automatically used the space added during that process. So again nothing to do there.

Comment: This is wrong on so many counts.

Comment: If this is wrong in any way, please elaborate or cite references.  After shrinking the Windows partition I was able to successfully expand (via gParted) the 16.04 partition

Comment: **You did it correct... you used Windows tools to shrink the Windows partition... and you used gparted to move/resize the Ubuntu partition.** In reference to the above... gparted message doesn't only pertain to lilo booted OS's... and the real whopper... that Ubuntu will automatically use the free space created without doing anything.

Comment: @heynnema: after resizing (enlarging) the 16.04 partition, is there another step I need to perform to configure Ubuntu to use the larger partition?

Comment: No. Of course, without seeing the screenshot of gparted that I asked for, I may be missing something. Well... you could do a chkdsk on the Windows partition, and a fsck on the Ubuntu partition.

Comment: ps: you could also do a `sudo fdisk -l` (or `sudo parted` to do a better job) and see if your partitions are aligned.

Comment: @heynnema: I have added an epilogue with the original configuration + the post-partition results of fdisk and gParted

Comment: When I removed the MacOS partition on the dual-boot MacBook Pro and tried to move the ubuntu partition to the left using gparted on a ubuntu USB, the gparted warning message worried me.  Based on this answer, I went ahead with the move and resize of the ubuntu (22.04) boot partition, and it indeed had no hassle.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me as well.
Reduced a partition on windows to get some unallocated space. Then, boot into Linux mint using Live USB. Using GParted I was able to resize the partition mounted on /

It did give me the same warning but completed successfully. Also, I read somewhere that the unallocated space should be next to the partition you want to extend(right or left). Mine was already next to it. Else, I believe you might have to do some extra steps. Right click on the partition and select resize, it will let you drag to expand the partition.

Answer (score 0):

As for Linux (with grub2), this worked well, but of course when Windows partition has been moved via GParted.

[In a similar question I have explained](https://superuser.com/a/1824646/522670) how to fix the Windows boot when it is broken  in such a case, re-creating the *Boot Configuration Data (BCD) store*. Actually, **this was the only thing I needed to do**, keep care not to break more stuff by overwriting your MBR or so, which contains a working grub so…

PS: Next time, try not moving the Windows partition or using Windows tools. (And Linux partitions using Linux tools like GParted.)